# File size different from SQL Server and PHP var_dump

Tags: php, sql-server, pdf

I have a problem with my project. I want to upload file (image / pdf) into SQL Server database. I already success at uploading the file to database.

The problem now when i load the pdf to php page, the file size change. So the pdf is consider to corrupt file.

[File size selected from SQL server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8y9wt.png)

[File size when i use VAR_DUMP()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTNht.png)

There is no problem with the image, both success at upload and load to the page. The problem only occur to the PDF file.

That's my problem, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Which number in the PDF are you using to compare against the string length from SQL Server. PDF Files are not simple files and contain all sorts of control structures. If you are looking at the `string(1048576)` number that is not the WHOLE file data content

Comment: I use SELECT query to get varbinary(max) value on SQL Server.

Then i put it in php variable named $FILE;

After that i use VAR_DUMP($FILE); and return string(1048576). it should be return string(1258967) i presume? because the pdf size is 1.25 mb