# PHP failed to load PDF larger than 1MB

Tags: php, pdf

I have a problem when I load PDF larger than 1MB into chrome pdf viewer. but no problem when load PDF smaller than 1MB.

[image: Here the picture when I load 800kb pdf]

[image: Here the picture when I load 1,8mb pdf]

And it's not only in chrome, but mozilla firefox can't load it either.

Here is my code :

```
`<?php 
    include "/MODEL/db.php";
    $sql = "SELECT SIUP from $DBVCE.VENDORREQUEST where ID='11079'";
    $query = mssql_query($sql,$con);
    while($query_db = mssql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $FILE = $query_db['SIUP'];
    }
    echo '<object height="100%" width="100%" 
    data="data:application/pdf;base64,'.base64_encode($FILE).'">';
?>`
```

The SIUP i selected in my query is varbinary(MAX). It's contains value like this (0xFFD8FFE12...)

Comment: Not really related to SQL Server is it?

Comment: You use PHP to load PDF? Can you show your code?

Comment: @TuanDuong here is my code `<?php 
include "/MODEL/db.php";
$sql = "SELECT SIUP from $DBVCE.VENDORREQUEST where ID='11080'";
$query = mssql_query($sql,$con);
while($query_db = mssql_fetch_assoc($query)){
 $FILE = $query_db['SIUP'];
}

echo '<object height="100%" width="100%" data="data:application/pdf;base64,'.base64_encode($FILE).'">';

?>

` the SIUP i selected is VARBINARY(MAX).

Comment: @DaleBurrell i think the problem is the SQL SERVER are not allowed me to SELECT more than 1048576 bytes. as you can see  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54324376/file-size-different-from-sql-server-and-php-var-dump?noredirect=1#comment95467489_54324376). But there is no problem with showing picture more than 1mb.

Comment: Please add your code to your question.

Comment: @DaleBurrell added my code above

Comment: Why not debug your code to see whether there is an issue selecting a large file from SQL Server?

Comment: @DaleBurrell I already found the problem and already post the answer. Thank you very much for your assistance btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It's happen because of my php variable can only contains to 1,048,576 bytes length. But my PDF file (in varbinary) is about 1,280,345 bytes. So i change the php.ini file like below

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3i7Z.png) and [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJL28.png)

Just change `mssql.textlimit = 1048576` to `mssql.textlimit = n` 

 And `mssql.textsize = 1048576` to `mssql.textsize = n` in php.ini file

 Where `n` is the length of text you desire

Comment: Hi, since those images are just of text output, it's probably easier for everyone if you just paste that text in the answer.

Comment: @IMSoP that is not text output. that screenshot of my php.ini file, but i gonna add it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to represent the entire document as a URL, encoded in base64, resulting in a URL several megabytes long. There's almost certainly a limit to the length the browser supports, and this is giving you your problem.

Rather than rendering an HTML page containing that URL, you can just echo the document content directly to the browser, and tell the browser the content type with an HTTP header:

```
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
echo $FILE;
```